# IE 10 AND IE 11 in windows 7 ultimate 32 bit does not support ajax post

Tags: ajax, windows, angularjs, internet-explorer, post

I am working in a web single page web application in angularjs and symfony2. I have used pure html for loading the application without using php. While I am trying to login through ajax call to the symfony server, the request sends without post values (username and email). But the application works in chrome very well. I have used ng-include and src to change my layouts to show different pages instead of using ng-route.

For Ref: My IE Version number is 11. Some sites suggests that use IE=9 Compatible mode using X-UA-Compatible. Then ajax post simply works. but after that when I try to change part of template using ng-include and src then I get the content but with status code 500. After that If I refresh the browser, it then gives 500 internal server error. I can able to access my application only after reopening the browser.

I have tried it with others systems which is using windows 7 ultimate and ie11, the application works well without any hassle. and I am using .net framework 4.5.1.

Note: the template files which i try to include using ng-include are pure html files and here there is no server call to symfony either.

it seems to be a problem in my OS or IE. What should I do here to get my IE working with ajax and other issues.